# how to record popup window using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Is there any way to record the popup window using jmeter? My requirement is to record the authentication window which contains username and password. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, while recording your script, Jmeter will capture all HTTP requests that use the port specified in the HTTP Proxy Server.  In this case, since the pop-up window is in the browser, Jmeter will capture it.

Answer (score 0):

Its a huge limitation of Jmeter. We can overcome the same by recording the popup separately and attaching them with the next forthcoming pages. The URL for the popup can be obtained from the developers

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way in which without record the popup window you can create a popup window request & with the help of you can login. Please follow the below link

http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter